# error with sql statement. trying to innerjoin table by row and then delete selected ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have attempted to innerjoin 2 tables and then delete the selected ids using "IN". It has given me an error and was wondering what I am doing incorrectly with this.

```
DELETE 

FROM 
  my_table b
INNER JOIN 
  my_table_assoc a
ON 
  b.foo_id= a.foo_id
WHERE  
  b.foo_id IN ($delete_list) ";
```

However, when I think about it this way it makes no sense because i am failing to delete the id in my_table_assoc. Do I need to use an outer join to delete the needed row in both tables simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DELETE does not delete columns, it deletes rows.

The syntax allows `DELETE b, a FROM ...` or `DELETE b.*, a.* FROM ...`.

It doesn't make any sense to list specific columns you want to delete.